# UI issues with custom NSBox

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, user-interface, nstextfield, nsbox

I have a subclassed NSBox. Inside I have some NSTextfields embedded, which show some strange artifacts in their corners (see [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDEYk.jpg)). This is my subclass code for the NSBox:

```
    - (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
    NSBezierPath* rectanglePath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect
                                                                  xRadius: 4
                                                                  yRadius: 4];
    [NSColor whiteColor];
    [rectanglePath fill];
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks, Thomas

Comment: Why are you using NSBox, if you are adding TextFields to it? Past a point, it would seem to make more sense to just use NSView.

Comment: stevesliva, I removed the NSBox and replaced it with a subclassed NSView. Same results. But when I checked Core Animation Layer in the View Effects Inspector these drawing issues disappeared. I do not understand what´s happening here.

Comment: I'd update your title and tags... you might get some more responses with the Core Animation query.

Comment: Sheen, this did not help. Artifacts are still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What solved the problem was using [self bounds] instead of the rect argument.

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
NSBezierPath* rectanglePath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:[self bounds]
                                                              xRadius: 4
                                                              yRadius: 4];
[NSColor whiteColor];
[rectanglePath fill];
```

}